# Jenkins Java build is failing to execute Putty PSCP

Tags: java, windows, jenkins, executable, pscp

I have a Java project that is being built remotely through Jenkins on a Windows server and running some Cucumber tests. Once the tests are finished running, I am creating a process to execute a Putty pscp command to transfer a file over to a linux server. The code works fine when I run it on my local..and it works fine when I manually run the pscp transfer command on the remote windows server where Jenkins is building the project. But for whatever reason when the project is built through Jenkins ...the command is not getting issued. Any ideas? The try Catch is printing out that it successfully has issued the command, however the transferred file is not showing up on the linux server as being updated...so I don't have any failure messages to help me debug this in the output logs.

Some assumptions which I've verified:

- The path I'm using for the file that is going to be transferred is correct.
- The file is not being transferred.

Some of the code:

```
    String updateJiraLocalPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\scripts\\updatejira.sh"; //Eclipse Project path

    ProcessBuilder process= new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Putty\\0.6.3\\PSCP.EXE", "-r", "-l", "username@servername", "-pw", "serverPassword", updateJiraLocalPath, "username@servername:/tmp/username/dirToTransferFile");

    p = process.start();

try {
            final int exitValue = p.waitFor();
            if (exitValue == 0){
                String line;
                System.out.println("Successfully executed the command);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                      }
               input.close();

            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Failed to execute the command: due to the following error(s):");
                try (final BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()))) {
                    String line;
                    if ((line = b.readLine()) != null)
                        System.out.println(line);
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println(e);
                }                
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Comment: `exitValue` ends up being 0 or -x ? Is anything printed out to the screen with system.out.println ? Did you use a debugger to step through this code?

Comment: @Dillon If you need to upload file from windows to linux, Jenkins has a lot of ways to do that without java. Jenkins engine has been optimized to ssh functionalities over servers and it will be more safe to use it instead of your java implementation.

Comment: @Shark, Yes it prints out the success message, however in my code I am also executing another command after that which prints out nothing. Even though it prints success...the file is not transferring to the Linux server

Comment: @JRichardsz I also need to run some commands which I have stored in a text file in the workspace - on the linux server. Can Jenkins do this post building my java project?

Comment: Have you considered that `cmd /c start C:\\Putty\\070\\pscp...` launches a `cmd.exe` process which _then launches a new process executing Putty **in the background**_?  Thus when you `waitFor()` you are waiting for the result of the `cmd`, and not the result of the `putty` command? You never see any error messages issued by Putty itself.  Use the newer `ProcessBuilder` API and execute Putty directly instead of through `cmd`.

Comment: @Jim Garrison   Thanks for suggestions Jim, I made the change to ProcessBuilder, and you were right..I am now getting proper success messages on both instances. However I am still facing the same issues where it is showing success..however files are not being transferred. I also have another command which will issue some commands on linux using PLINK.exe and that is not working either ><

Comment: You missed the point of my first comment.  If you do `cmd start putty` the output from `putty` is discarded.  You need to eliminate both `cmd` and `start` and execute `putty` _directly_.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you call `waitFor()` twice.

Comment: @JimGarrison I updated code to reflect your suggestions - can see change above - but still same issue, and surprisingly now I'm not getting any success, failure, or exception messages.

Comment: Yes @Dillon, jenkins could execute commands in remote linux using direct commands o scripts.